# Defining a Non-Linear System of Equations involving max and min with as a contraction

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose I have a vector of strictly positive variables $X \in \mathbb{R}_{++}^{J}$ and a vector of strictly positive variables $Y \in \mathbb{R}_{++}^{I}$ and I want to find the values for which a function $F(X,Y):\mathbb{R}^{J+I}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{J+I}$ is equal to $0$, $F(X^{*},Y^{*})=0$, where the function F is defined as

\begin{align}
   F(X,Y)  &= \begin{bmatrix}
           X_{1} - a_{1} \left[ \min_{i} \left\{ c_{i1} Y_{i}^{\frac{1-\eta}{\eta}} \right\}\right]^{-\delta} \\
           \vdots \\
           X_{J} - a_{J} \left[ \min_{i} \left\{ c_{iJ} Y_{i}^{\frac{1-\eta}{\eta}} \right\}\right]^{-\delta} \\
           Y_{1} - b_{1} \left[ \max_{j} \left\{ d_{1j} X_{j}^{-\frac{1}{\delta}} \right\}\right]^{\frac{\eta}{1-\eta}}  \\
           \vdots \\
           Y_{I} - b_{I} \left[ \max_{j} \left\{ d_{Ij} X_{j}^{-\frac{1}{\delta}} \right\}\right]^{\frac{\eta}{1-\eta}}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

where $a_{j},b_{i},c_{ij}$ and $d_{ij}$ are positive constants and $\eta\in (0,1) $ and $\delta>1$ are parameters. As you can see, all the values of $X$ depend on all the values of $Y$ and vice-versa.

Is there a way to solve this system of nonlinear equations analytically and get a closed-form expression, or the only way is plugging it in the computer. If the only way is numerical, are there any useful properties that one can exploit?

My **first impression** is that it is **not possible** to solve this analytically. Computationally, my first hunch was that one could show that this is a ***Contraction Mapping*** and, then, an iterative procedure would yield the **unique** solution. However, I have not been able to show this.

---

Solution Attempt #1 ***This solution is clearly wrong. I am not deleting it to show my own try.***

Notice that we can write the whole system of equations in terms of just one of the vectors. I am going to pick vector $X$.

Then,

\begin{align}
   \tilde{F}(X)  &= \begin{bmatrix}
           X_{1} - a_{1} \left[ \min_{i} \left\{ c_{i1} b_{i}^{\frac{1-\eta}{\eta}} \max_{\ell} \left\{ d_{i\ell} X_{\ell}^{-\frac{1}{\delta}} \right\} \right\}\right]^{-\delta} \\
           \vdots \\
           X_{J} - a_{J} \left[ \min_{i} \left\{ c_{iJ} b_{i}^{\frac{1-\eta}{\eta}} \max_{\ell} \left\{ d_{i\ell} X_{\ell}^{-\frac{1}{\delta}} \right\} \right\}\right]^{-\delta} \\
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

Clearly, this system of equations needs to have a fixed point, i.e for the $i$ that minimizes the value in the $j$th equation it must be that $a_{j}\left(c_{i(j)j}b_{i(j)}^{\frac{1-\eta}{\eta}}d_{i(j)j}\right)^{-\delta}=1$. So this is a condition, on the values of the parameters that must hold. I know it seems weird that I am assuming it ex-post, but I am collapsing a more complicated function of the parameters into these constants. So then, this function $\tilde{F}$ indeed has a fixed point.

Then, the next step would be showing that this mapping is a contraction, which means I could solve it iteratively on the computer. **However, here is where I am getting stuck.**

However, I am wondering if there is a way to solve this in a more efficient or a way to get a closed-form solution or, at least, a sharper characterization of the solution.

---

Solution Attempt #2 ***Incomplete***

Another approach that might be worth mentioning is that this system can be written linearly (still with the max and the min) as follows. Let $\hat{Y}_{i} = Y_{i}^{\frac{1-\eta}{\eta}}$ and $\hat{X}_{i} = X_{i}^{-\frac{1}{\delta}}$. Then, the system of equations becomes

\begin{align}
   \hat{F}(\hat{X},\hat{Y})  &= \begin{bmatrix}
           \hat{X_{1}} - a_{1} \left[ \min_{i} \left\{ c_{i1} \hat{Y_{i}} \right\}\right] \\
           \vdots \\
           \hat{X_{J}} - a_{J} \left[ \min_{i} \left\{ c_{iJ} \hat{Y_{i}} \right\}\right] \\
           \hat{Y_{1}} - b_{1} \left[ \max_{j} \left\{ d_{1j} \hat{X_{j}}\right\}\right]  \\
           \vdots \\
           \hat{Y_{I}} - b_{I} \left[ \max_{j} \left\{ d_{Ij} \hat{X_{j}}\right\}\right]
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

---

Any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The range of F should be J+I

Comment: @CharlesF yes of course. You are totally right. It is corrected. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Anyone has any idea?

Comment: It seems unlikely that you’ll find a substitution that would allow you to find the solutions analytically. If you can, I would probably give up on that, and instead try a subgradient numerical method to minimize the L2 norm of F hat. Try a few initial conditions to figure out where local minima exist. That might work to help you understand the sensitivity of this system in your parameters.

Comment: Thanks so much, @CharlesF. That makes sense. I agree that finding analytical solutions is impossible. My first idea was that I could write this problem as a contraction and that an iterative procedure would work. However, this does not seem to be doing the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Numerical aspects of your 2nd approach**

For notational simplicity, here $X_1$ is your $\hat{X}_1$, etc.

Consider a simple example:
\begin{align*}
 X_1 &= a_1 \min(c_{11}Y_1, c_{21}Y_2, c_{31}Y_3), \\
 X_2 &= a_2 \min(c_{12}Y_1, c_{22}Y_2, c_{32}Y_3), \\
 Y_1 &= b_1 \max(d_{11}X_1, d_{12}X_2), \\
 Y_2 &= b_2 \max(d_{21}X_1, d_{22}X_2),\\
 Y_3 &= b_3 \max(d_{31}X_1, d_{32}X_2). \qquad (S)
\end{align*}

Consider the following optimization problem:
\begin{align*}
 &\min_{X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2, Y_3} ~ Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3 - X_1 - X_2 \qquad (P)\\
 &\mathrm{subject ~ to}\quad X_1 \le a_1 c_{i1}Y_i, \quad i = 1, 2, 3;\\
 &\qquad\qquad\quad\ X_2 \le a_2 c_{i2}Y_i, \quad i = 1, 2, 3; \\
    &\qquad\qquad\quad\
    Y_1 \ge b_1 d_{1j}X_j, \quad j = 1, 2;\\
    &\qquad\qquad\quad\
    Y_2 \ge b_2 d_{2j}X_j, \quad j = 1, 2;\\
    &\qquad\qquad\quad\
    Y_3 \ge b_3 d_{3j}X_j, \quad j = 1, 2;\\
    &\qquad\qquad\quad\
    X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2, Y_3 \ge 0; \\
    &\qquad\qquad\quad\
    X_1 + X_2 \ge 1.
\end{align*}
The additional constraint $X_1 + X_2 \ge 1$ is to avoid the zero solution (since the system is homogeneous).

If the system (S) has a solution, then the feasible region of the problem (P) is non-empty.
Let $(X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2, Y_3)$ be the solution to the problem (P), then it is a solution to the system (S).

I used Matlab to do some numerical experiment.